# vue-cli with vuetify in codesandbox malfunctioning

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, codesandbox

The same project that runs perfectly in my computer is giving me warnings in codesandbox. Why does this happens?

codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Tauromachian/vue-select-list

github

https://github.com/Tauromachian/vue-select-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your file `plugins/vuetify.js`

change the line

`import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";`

to

`import Vuetify from "vuetify";`

Comment: Why i can't import from vuetify/lib?